# Predator Prey Model - Discrete Linear Dynamical Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I've just started learning Predator-Prey Models for the first time, though I find this question slightly strange.

Some animals have the ability to change sex if the population size gets too biased toward any one gender. It was found that in a particular group of fish the number of male and female fish follows the following equation:

\begin{eqnarray}
M_{k+1}=0.8M_{k} + 0.1F_{k}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{k+1}=-pM_{k} + 1.1F_{k}
\end{eqnarray}

$M_{k}$ and $F_{k}$ - number of male and female fish after k years respectively.

p is some positive constant.

I am required to **find p** so that the number of fish **approaches a finite, non-zero limit.**

I understand that normally you will have to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors:

Starting off I would get matrix A:
\begin{bmatrix}
0.8 & 0.1\\
-p & 1.1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Finding eigenvalues by solving $det(A-\lambda I)$:
\begin{bmatrix}
0.8-\lambda & 0.1\\
-p & 1.1-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix}

I have: $det(A-\lambda I)=(0.8-\lambda)(1.1-\lambda)+0.1p$ but I can't help thinking that this step is unnecessary. Not too sure how this will help in finding p.

Many thanks in advance for any clarification/explanation.

Comment: The number of fish approaches a finite, non-zero limit iff (baring pathological initial conditions) only if $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: I see.  Would it be correct to say that p=0.2 @A.S.? Thank you so much for the clarification!